# How to reduce fontsize for References when using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{anderson,
Address = {Mahwah, New Jersey},
Author = {J. R. Anderson},
Date-Added = {2014-02-05 15:27:59 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-05 16:10:22 +0100},
Publisher = {Lawrence {E}rlbaum {A}ssociates},
Title = {The architecture of cognition},
Year = {1983}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \chapter*{\refname}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}%
\small\list{}{%
  \usecounter{enumi}%
  \leftmargin 1em\itemindent -1em\parsep \z@
    \itemsep4\p@%
 }}%
{\endlist}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Test for reference entry \citep{anderson}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Above tags are working fine, but not able to change the turnover (hangindent) value and the fontsize of the entries. Please suggest....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `biblatex` does not use `thebibliography`, you don't need to redefine that environment and any redefinition will not not affect the `biblatex`-generated bibliography.

The size of the hanging indent is controlled by the length `\bibhang`, which is defined as

```
 \setlength{\bibhang}{\ifnumequal{\parindent}{0}{1em}{\parindent}}
```

in `biblatex.def` and redefined to

```
 \setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
```

in `biblatex-chicago.sty`.

You could try `\setlength{\bibhang}{\parindent}` or `\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Test for reference entry \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with 1em hanging indent.]

The font size can be changed with

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}
```

Just replace `\normalsize` with the size command for the size you want.

---

Some more details.

The default bibliography environment in `biblatex-chicago` is defined as

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}% New for 0.9a
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

If you want to add additional space to the left, you could say something like

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}
\newlength{\bibleftadd}
\setlength{\bibleftadd}{1cm}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibleftadd}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Test for reference entry \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much thanks for this, its working like a champ....

Comment: Is this possible to fix some left skip globally, that is, entire references should be indent by 2pc from left and the hangindent should be `2pc+9pt`? Kindly advise....

Comment: please suggest is that possible to global indentation as my mentioned in my previous `comment`, ....please...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Have a look at the edit, please?

Comment: It's working like a champ... Thanks a lot....